# Why aggregate rating isn't understood by google?

Tags: schema.org

I want google to show rich snippet with aggregate rating for the following html snippet:
http://goo.gl/IApGCs. But for some reason google doen't show aggregate rating for this snippet, but if I substitude the attribute itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" for itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant" then google shows aggregate rating.

What I should to do to make google show the aggregate rating exactly with itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google generally does not display rich snippets for Organization rating markups, at least not at the present time.  They do, however, show the rating rich snippet for such things as hotels, restaurants, local businesses, and products.  So you can try using a different markup for your business if it's appropriate and hopefully the rich snippet will be generated.